# Is there a way to specify the name of each Json Header when serializing a dictionary?

Tags: c#, json.net

I have the following JSON which is serialized from a hashset `Hashset<RootObject,List<Messages>>`

```
{
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": [],
  "GasmonConsole.RootObject": []
}
```

Where RootObject is

```
public class RootObject
{
    public double x { get; set; }
    public double y { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

I am using JSON.NET like this: `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tracker,Formatting.Indented);` to serialize the Hashset.

The values exports perfectly when I fill this hashset with data but the headers(Key in the sash) where it says `"GasmonConsole.RootObject"`isn't useful as it doesn't allow me to identify which object is which. I have tried some of the [examples](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingCollections.htm) I think relate to my issue on the JSON.NET documentation but none of them see to work.

I am looking to have the headers be the ID of the RootObject (example below) but as I said I have tried the example above and it didn't work. Is this possible and if so could someone please point me in the right direction?

```
{
  "111": [],
  "112": [],
  "113": []
}
```

I also apologize if header is the wrong term to refer to these values as.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you only need the Id mapper with the collection of messages. If that's the case then you should pass the following for Deserialization:

```
Hashset<int,List<Messages>>
```

while the key would the `RootObject`'s `Id` property.